# Transfer data from one page to another jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I using PhoneGap to create a Geolocation App following this excellent tutorial ([link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-exercise-tracking-app-persistence-graphing--mobile-11074)). Unfortunatelly, I'm having an issue that I can't figure out. The relevant parts that are giving me a headache are these:

```
//Section 1

$('#history').on('pageshow', function () {

tracks_recorded = window.localStorage.length;
$("#tracks_recorded").html("<strong>" + tracks_recorded + "</strong> workout(s) recorded");

$("#history_tracklist").empty();

for (i = 0; i < tracks_recorded; i++) {
    $("#history_tracklist").append("<li><a href='#track_info' data-ajax='false'>" + window.localStorage.key(i) + "</a></li>");
}

$("#history_tracklist").listview('refresh');
});

//Section 2

$("#history_tracklist li a").on('click', function () {

$("#track_info").attr("track_id", $(this).text());

});
```

//Section 3

```
$('#track_info').on('pageshow', function () {

var key = $(this).attr("track_id");

$("#track_info div[data-role=header] h1").text(key);

var data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

data = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Section 1 works just fine, the data is stored, and the list is created without any issues. But then in Section 2 is when everything goes to hell. By clicking on the  element, a new attribute (track_id) is supposed to be created, but it doesn't. Therefore, in Section 3, the "var key" won't get a value, and as a consequence, "var data" will be null also. As you can imagine, nothing works from there. What am I doing wrong here? I only included what I considered the relevant code, but if more is needed I'll do so. Thansk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In section 2, I think you just need to delegate click handling to the "#history_tracklist" container, as follows :

```
$("#history_tracklist").on('click', "li a", function () {
    $("#track_info").attr("track_id", $(this).text());
});
```

Without delegation you have a rule saying :

> when any existing `li a` element within `#history_tracklist` is clicked execute my function

With delegation, you have a rule saying :

> when any existing *or future* `li a` element within `#history_tracklist` is clicked execute my function

Comment: Nailed it! Brilliant solution.

Comment: Pleased to be of help @cubanGuy.